# no funciona removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy intentando eliminar un evento de un button cualquiera.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 <button id="btn__sin" class="btn  btn__register">continuar sin</button>
 <button id="btn__con" class="btn btn__register">continuar</button>
```

Y su js:

```
let btn__sin = document.getElementById('btn__sin');

 btn__sin.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  checkOption(btn__sin);
});

 checkOption = ( opcion__btn ) =>{
    btn__sin.removeEventListener('click',checkOption);

   console.log('hola');

 };
```

Si le doy al boton, me sale de forma reiterada en cada click "hola". 
Me debería de eliminar el evento pero no me lo elimina.

Answer (score 2):

**El problema:**

Al agregar el `addEventListener` le estas pasando una función anónima la cual no puedes remover mas adelante de una forma simple.

**La solución:**

El `addEventListener` debe tener como segundo parámetro una función declarada que luego puedas usar como referencia en el `removeEventListener`.

Algo como:

```
let btn__sin = document.getElementById('btn__sin');

function clickEventHandle(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  checkOption(btn__sin);
}

btn__sin.addEventListener('click', clickEventHandle);

checkOption = ( opcion__btn ) =>{
  btn__sin.removeEventListener('click', clickEventHandle);
  console.log('hola');
};
```